# Eclipse che cannot deploy web application archive

Tags: eclipse, docker, virtual-machine, eclipse-che

I'm trying to run eclipse che and i'm stuck. Everything runs fine until the 3rd step of workspace creation "injecting and starting workspace agent".
After `deploying web application archive` it just shows an error that the workspace agent is not responding and it will be stopped. There isn't any other error during the initialization and everything seems to load fine. I suppose

I got the same issue on both windows (8 and 10) and ubuntu latest LTS. I suppose docker is responsible for the error but i can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling everything, and downloading the docker toolbox manually solved the issue on windows. Seems like the eclipse che installer has some version issues.